# How do I create a custom method to convert unix timestamp to UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I'm using this quite a bit to convert Unix timestamps that I receive from a third-party API, into UTC datetimes:

```
Time.at(1386549840).utc.to_datetime
```

How can I create a custom method to keep from repeating that so much? I use this primarily in my models and some background job workers.

Something like:

```
1386549840.convert_to_utc
```

This happens to be in a Rails 4 app using Ruby 2.0, FWIW.

Comment: An actual UNIX timestamp should already be UTC, by definition. Are you getting bad data from the third party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a method yourself to do it:

```
class Fixnum
  def convert_to_utc
    Time.at(self).utc.to_datetime
  end
end
```

Classes in Ruby are open for extension.